# Ignore file types in svn

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Some file types (suo, dll, pdb) kept causing conflicts in our svn repository so I went ahead and set those file types to be ignored by svn. When I try a new commit now the file types still show up in the list of files that are to be commited. I am assuming this is because the files are already under source control. How do I ensure the files do not show up when trying t commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you guessed, it is because those files are already being tracked by SVN. SVN-ignore only works for files that are not in the repository.

Therefore, you should remove the files (using `svn delete`) from the working copy, commit that, and then you should be ok.

You should probably ignore the whole build output directory, as you don't want to commit any of the files that are built, no matter what their file type.

Answer (score 3):

Sound like you need to `svn remove` the files in question.  If they have already been added to your Subversion repo, you have to tell Subversion to stop tracking it.  `svn ignore` will only ignore files that have not already been added to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you set svn:ignore, it only prevents new files from being added. Plus, it doesn't prevent someone from adding files anyway. You can override the `svn:ignore`.

What you may want is a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that will prevent someone from adding these files to the repository first place. In this hook, you can specify the files you don't want committed as `read-only`, so no one can commit them, or you can setup a ban section, and ban them through out the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Avi, easier to ignore generated directories in their entirety.  On our team we typically use the following svn-ignore settings:

At the project level:

- bin
- obj
- *.user

At the solution level:

- *.suo